# Virtual box not starting in Trusty Thar, i get the following error

Tags: virtualbox

I could run VirtualBox on Ubuntu 12.04 with no problems, after updating to trusty, when I attempted to run VirtualBox I got the following error, tried reinstalling but I get the same error. Here is the error message:

```
 Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object.
The application will now terminate.
Start tag expected, '<' not found.
Location: '/home/chiku/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml', line 1 (0), column 1.
/build/buildd/virtualbox-4.3.10-dfsg/src/VBox/Main/src-server/VirtualBoxImpl.cpp[531] (nsresult VirtualBox::init()).
```

Comment: can you please post contents of `~/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml` ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the location of that file in 14.04 is now located in ~/.config/VirtualBox instead of ~/.VirtualBox .

Open nautilus, thunar, dolphin, or your file manager as sudo like this:

```
sudo nautilus /home/chiku
```

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files.

Next, rename the directory ".VirtualBox" to something else like "VirtualCopy" instead.

Then, try starting VirtualBox to see if the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
mv /home/chiku/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml /home/chiku/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml.bk
```

Its similar to the fix suggested by @mchid.
Worked for me